# How to set the default text for the share option of the PlusOneButton dialog

Tags: java, android, google-plus, google-plus-one

I have implemented a Google Plus One button and everything works ok. Now my question: After the user clicks on the button, a dialog activity shows up. This dialog activity has 3 buttons: Undo, Share and Accept. When clicking on Share button, the it shows up the Google+ share activity, where you select who you want to share with, and then, the text you want to show on the share post. I wonder how I could set up the default text to show on the share post. I have already implemented a Google+ share button, which code looks like this on the click listener:

```
Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(MainActivity.this)
    .setType("text/plain")
    .setText("This is the default text I want to set up in the PlusOneButton")
    .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://URL"))
    .getIntent();

startActivityForResult(shareIntent, 0);
```

How could I set the default text when the user clicks on the Share button of the dialog activity that shows up just after the user clicks on the Plus One button? Is there any way of doing this similar as I did for the Share button I implemented?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever mange to work this out?